# How can i store camlquery results to filter and delete that i don't need?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, caml-query, caml

I just want to change the result of camlquery. But i dont know how to store them and filter it. The query is now turning many values that i dont need. I want to drop them and show them in a view. So, how can i manipulate this camlquery results?

Answer (score 0):

Are you handling SharePoint list view with caml query? If so, you can use 3rd party tools like Caml designer to help you build the query you need.

Source:https://www.biwug.be/resources